# I want to edit lk.img to support fastboot binaries

Tags: fastboot, partitions, oppo

based on what i found
Oppo removed the fastboot binaries from my phone (Oppo A5s)
and since the lk partition is the one that have it by default
i would like to know how can i sort of inject the binaries into this partition

Comment: without source code this question is better placed [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com). what's the deal with this [workaround](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tutorial-oppo-a-x-5s-bootloader-unlocking-tutorial.4539167) by you?

Comment: i just want to change the stock rom because it sucks and it's outdated
i tried GSI roms but they hve many issues so at least i want to have root access
technically that guide needs an update because that method is extremely risky (i lost my IMEI because of it)